# Why do all applications go to the 'Others' App Folder in Gnome Shell 3.8?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, application, menu

I just upgraded my laptop to Fedora 19, which comes with Gnome Shell 3.8. Gnome shell 3.8 has got rid of the traditional Categories in favor of something called App Folders.

I have been trying to learn how to create and use them. One thing I have not been able to understand is why the 'Others' menu/app folder has all my apps.

In `/etc/xdg/menus/gnome-applications.menu` it is defined like:

```
    <Name>Other</Name>
    <Directory>X-GNOME-Other.directory</Directory>
    <OnlyUnallocated/>
    <Include>
      <And>
        <Not><Category>Core</Category></Not>
        <Not><Category>Screensaver</Category></Not>

        <!-- Really Fedora ??? -->
        <Not><Filename>gnome-eog.desktop</Filename></Not>
        <Not><Filename>gnome-file-roller.desktop</Filename></Not>
        <Not><Filename>gnome-gucharmap.desktop</Filename></Not>
      </And>
    </Include>
  </Menu> <!-- End Other -->
```

I read from some spec that `<OnlyUnallocated/>` tag should only match, and add to the menu, applications that have not been matched to any other menu. I also do not see where it decides to include the apps, as `<Include></Include>` just contains apps *not* to include. I assume it is either defined somewhere else, or the name 'Other' is just somewhat special.

Am I understanding something wrong about the definition of these menus, or is Gnome Shell 3.8 doing it's own thing, and not working 100% according to these files? (I suspect the former)